# How to distinguish between Pointer and TObject entries in a TStringList?

Tags: delphi

We can add strings along with some associated objects to a TStringList:

```
list: TStringList;
obj: MyObject;

obj := MyObject.Create();
list.AddObject("real object", obj);
```

In addition it can be very handy to simply connect a string with a Pointer, i.e., an integer value, like this:

```
list.AddObject("just an index", Pointer(7));
```

If I later access to an object in this list how to know if it is a MyObject or simply a Pointer? I want something like this:

```
for i := 0 to list.Count-1 do
  if list.Objects[i] is MyObject then
  begin
    // ...
    // Do something with list.Objects[i]
    // ...
  end;
```

but this obviously leads to access violation if **list.Objects[i]** is just a Pointer. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best solution is to not mix the two. If you want to store objects, store objects, and then you can compare to `nil` or use `Assigned`. If you want to store integers, store integers (which is what `Pointer(7)` does - it's not storing a *pointer*, it's storing an integer typecast as a pointer to get past the compiler complaining).

Comment: In general you can assume that addresses lower than about $FFFF are fake pointers - not objects, you don't have read access to that memory range. Alas, I can't find documentation to back that up.

Comment: This question betrays either curiosity (good) or recklessness (bad). Avoid using unsafe or broken ideas like this in real code, or bad bad things will happen. If it is curiosity, as I will assume here, then kudos for thinking through this issue. Why not stick to Tobjects and make a data holder? Tmyintegerdata ...

Comment: Not mixing is the best idea, I agree. :-) I encountered this usage in external code parts and i was just wondering if there is a really nice solution for this "mixing problem", hence curiosity. Thanks to all! –

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to safely store both integers and objects into one stringlist, define a variant container class to hold integers or objects.

Below is such a class roughly outlined including a test project.

```
unit VariantContainer;

interface

uses Variants,SysUtils;

Type
  TVariantContainer = class
    private
      FVariant : Variant;
    public
      constructor Create(aValue: Integer); overload;
      constructor Create(aValue: TObject); overload;
      function IsInteger: Boolean;
      function IsObject: Boolean;
      function AsObject: TObject;
      function AsInteger: Integer;
  end;

implementation

function TVariantContainer.AsInteger: Integer;
begin
  if not IsInteger then
    raise Exception.Create('Variant is not Integer');
  Result := FVariant;    
end;

function TVariantContainer.AsObject: TObject;
begin
  if not IsObject then
    raise Exception.Create('Variant is not TObject');
  Result := TVarData(FVariant).VPointer;
end;

function TVariantContainer.IsInteger: Boolean;
begin
  Result := VarIsType( FVariant, varInteger);
end;

function TVariantContainer.IsObject: Boolean;
begin
  Result := VarIsType(FVariant, varByRef);
end;

constructor TVariantContainer.Create(aValue: Integer);
begin
  Inherited Create;
  FVariant := aValue;
end;

constructor TVariantContainer.Create(aValue: TObject);
begin
  Inherited Create;
  TVarData(FVariant).VType:= VarByRef;
  TVarData(FVariant).VPointer:= aValue;
end;

end.
```

---

```
program ProjectTestVariantContainer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Variants,SysUtils,Classes,VariantContainer;

Type
  TMyObj = class
    s:String;
  end;

var
  sList: TStringList;
  o: TMyObj;
  i: Integer;
begin
  o := TMyObj.Create;
  o.s := 'Hello';
  sList := TStringList.Create;
  sList.OwnsObjects := True;  // List owns container objects
  sList.AddObject('AnInteger',TVariantContainer.Create(3));
  sList.AddObject('AnObject',TVariantContainer.Create(o));
  for i := 0 to sList.Count-1 do
  begin
    if Assigned(sList.Objects[i]) then 
    begin
      if TVariantContainer(sList.Objects[i]).IsInteger then
        WriteLn( TVariantContainer(sList.Objects[i]).AsInteger)
      else
      if TVariantContainer(sList.Objects[i]).IsObject then
        WriteLn( TMyObj(TVariantContainer(sList.Objects[i]).AsObject).s);
    end;
  end;
  ReadLn;
  o.Free;
  sList.Free;  
end.
```

Comment: Don't forget to free the `TVariantContainer` objects before freeing the `TStringList` (unless you set its `OwnsObjects` property to True - XE2+ only) or else you will leak memory.

Comment: Yes, this kind of refactoring would work, but I was wondering if there is a nice, short way to check without need for this kind of changes. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: +1 but is there a reason you are actually using a `Variant` as backing field instead of an `Integer` or `Pointer`?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, using one variant internally or separate integer,tObject variables would work as well. My thought with using a variant was if you wanted to add more types, a variant could handle them as well.

Comment: @grafd, you can cut corners and make assumptions, but if you want a solid solution, something like this has to be done.

Answer (score 5):

> It's perfectly possible to add an integer wich just happens to point
>   to an object. Likewise it's perfectly possible to have a pointer to an
>   object in your list where the object already has been freed.

Bottom line, you can start looking around in memory all you want, **there is no bulletproof way** to know if your stringlist contains integers or pointers.

As you shouldn't mix different types anyway, there's also no *need* to know. A better approach would be to create two classes *containing* a Stringlist and make the outer classes type safe to work with. Your problem then becomes a non-issue.

**Example**  *assuming your Delphi version doesn't support generics*

```
  TStringIntegerMap = class
    private FStringIntegerList: TStringList;
  public
    procedure Add(const Key: string; Value: Integer);
    ... // Add the other required equivalent TStringlist methods 
  end;

  TStringObjectMap = class
    private FStringObjectList: TStringList;
  public
    procedure Add(const Key: string; Value: TObject);
    ... // Add the other required equivalent TStringlist methods 
  end;
```

*Note that this is just to give you the gist of how you might implement such classes.*

Comment: If I could easily separate the one string list in two then this would be a way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A TObject is in fact a pointer. So there is simply no way to distinguish between a pointer and a TObject considering that the latter is a former.

If you know something about an object, and you need to retrieve that knowledge at a later time, don't throw away that knowledge. If you need to know something later, remember it.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidHeffernan correctly pointed out, class types are pointers, so they are semantically equivalent and there is no way to distinguish them without having some type indication stored.

However, if you going to ask ***"How to find out if given arbitrary pointer points to the object instance?"*** there is a solution for that:

```
/// <summary>
///   Verifies that the argument points to valid object instance.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="EAccessViolation">
///   If segmentation fault occurs while reading VMT and/or its field from the
///   specified memory address.
/// </exception>
/// <remarks>
///   Delphi only, incompatible with FPC.
/// </remarks>
/// <example>
///   <code>
/// procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
/// begin
///   ShowMessage(BoolToStr(IsInstance(Self), True));
/// end;
///  </code>
/// </example>
function IsInstance(Data: Pointer): Boolean;
var
  VMT: Pointer;
begin
  VMT := PPointer(Data)^;
  Result := PPointer(PByte(VMT) + vmtSelfPtr)^ = VMT;
end;
```

I've posted whole inline documentation, so I feel that more comments are unnecessary, but I want to recap what intentionally invalid pointers like `Pointer(7)` of your example will certainly cause an access violation fault. So you can perform a preliminary check if the higher `Word`s of the pointer are zero (just the same logic as in [`Windows.IS_INTRESOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648028) macro:

```
function Is_IntResource(lpszType: PChar): BOOL;
begin
  Result := ULONG_PTR(lpszType) shr 16 = 0;
end;
```